# Using variable in echoed string, how to "end" variable?

Tags: php, echo

where $q is q

```
echo "asd$q";
```

will output asdq

```
echo "asd$q_";
```

will look for $q_ and since thats null, it will print asd

to get "asdq_" what should I do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can concatenate the variable with the string using `.`

```
$q='q';
echo 'asd'.$q.'_';
```

Answer (score 3):

Do like this.. Enclose the `$q` variable under curly braces.

```
<?php
$q='q';
echo "asd{$q}_"; //"prints" asdq_
```